# How can I create an Empty ExtJS application in Sencha Cmd

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-cmd

I am new to sencha cmd and I am trying to just make a blank app in a folder, without all these random starter views, stores, and models. I am currently doing `sencha -sdk C:\ExtJS\ext-7.5.1 generate app MyApp .` and this is making a starter template it seems, I want an empty one. Basically I have an old View that is a .js and I want to copy it into this new view folder, but I can't get it to show because It keeps trying to reference these old views called MainController and MainModel.

Comment: A view without model and controller is useless anyway; this is frontend MVC.

Answer (score 1):

sencha -sdk C:\ExtJS\ext-7.5.1 generate app **-starter=false** AppName .

The answer is to use **-starter=false**